# Rendering problem, weird distortion on blender 2.91

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, compositing-nodes, hardware

when rendering this i face strange issues on some frames like 5 o 6 of 281, they are specific frames,[image: Render]
only happens when rendering final image, but in viewport rendering mode it looks good

Comment: Looks pretty cool ngl, please consider uploading your blend file so as to have more info to diagnose your problem. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a correctly rendered image? Or are they all screwy like this?